# Highlighting the "full width avaialble" to a list item

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for a small law office. In the side-menu, I'm trying to highlight the "current page".  I have tried changing the background of the LI, but this doesn't quite do the trick; the list item doesn't spread to the full width of the menu, so it looks bad.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fEYx/3/).  I would like the yellow section to highlight like the pink section is highlighted: filling up the full vertical and horizontal space, not just highlighting the text.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I've included the style tag in the html just for example, obviously, and my real solution will be a little different when it's done.  But I can't move forward until I figure out how to somehow highlight the entire line.

Comment: If you're not using Firebug in Firefox with right-click, 'Inspect Element', I highly suggest it (Chrome has a native version); you can edit your html and css live to work out these kinds of problems. http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One little issue: you're mixing `em` and `px` units for layout. This makes it a lot harder when trying to make things line up.

[image]

I've implemented it using a `.selected` class that would be applied to the selected elements, and a special case for the elements which are sub-menu items:

```
.selected
{
    display: block;
    background-color:  #FCFFEE;
    width: 15.4em;
    margin-left: -0.6em;
    padding-left: 0.6em;
}

.subMenuItem.selected
{
    display: block;
    background-color:  #FCFFEE;
    width: 13.4em;
    margin-left: -2.6em;
    padding-left: 2.6em;
}
```

And a jsFiddle fork of your original with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/CkKc7/2/.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, especially for pointing out the PX/EM thing.  I'm really teaching myself CSS/html from scratch.

Comment: It's workable, but I prefer to use one or the other. I use pixels, but sometimes `em` is better for the job (like for typographically based pages, as `em` is based on font sizes). I think we all learned it from scratch one way or another ;)

Comment: Hmm. This solution sends any bullets (circles, squares, etc) outside the border of the  menu. [link to screen shot](http://richardmeinderslaw.com/problem.png).  Is there a way to keep the rest of your solution but fix this problem?

Comment: Oops!  Got it myself.  Just need to put this in there: list-style-position: inside;

Comment: For anyone using this solution in the future: it appears that display:block is extraneous [link to fiddle without display:block](http://jsfiddle.net/CkKc7/5/), and it causes bullets to disappear in some browsers.  My final solution has left display:block off.

Comment: +1 for the negative  margin, but this is not a generic solution, it's hardcoded for a menu with 2 levels...

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the `padding-left` from the `ul`. Also remove the `width`.
- Add `display: block` to the `<a>` tags.
- Add the removed `padding-left` back, but on the `<a>` tags instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/7fEYx/4/

Comment: How do I get it to work for the submenu?  I'm having trouble with setting the a of .subMenu. Otherwise this works perfectly.

Comment: I thought you wanted it as I had it (with the space to the left). @Blender's answer looks fine to me, but here's a further fixed version anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/7fEYx/6/ - I did a similar thing to before; removed the `padding-left` from the `ul`, and added it to the `li` (because the `li` has the `background-color`, in this case).

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to go with Blender's answer because it happened to fit my code a little nicer, but yours seemed like a fine solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
            <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.htm" style="background-color: yellow; display: block;" title="Contact Us">Contact</a></li>
```

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You should apply your style to the LI parent of the A tag, or make the A tag element block-level. Also, consider using a class instead.