# Is there anything "wrong" with this markup?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c, w3c-validation

Here is the markup I'm using:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="planning_menuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/" title="Estate Planning">Estate Planning</a></li>
    <ul class="subMenu">
        <li id="will_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/last_will_and_testament.htm" title="Last Will and Testaments">Last Will &amp; Testament</a></li>
        <li id="poa_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/power_of_attorney.htm">Power Of Attorney</a></li>
        <li id="livingWill_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/living_will.htm">Living Will</a></li>
        <li id="trusts_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/trusts.htm">Trusts</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li id="probate_menuItem" class="menuItem">
        <a href="probate_administration.htm" title="Estate Administration">Estate Probate Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li id="realEstate_menuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="#" title="Real Estate Transactions">Real Estate</a></li>         
    <li id="medicaid_MenuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="#" title="">Medicaid</a></li>
    <li id="guardianships_menuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="#" title="">Guardianships</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there anything stylistically wrong about having that "ul" (class=subMenu) in the middle of a list without it having it's own li tag?  This particular mark-up solves my problem, but I want at least be aware of whether I'm breaking some standard or convention.

The alternative is as follows, but it doesn't work for my particular task.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="planning_menuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/" title="Estate Planning">Estate Planning</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
        <li id="will_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/last_will_and_testament.htm" title="Last Will and Testaments">Last Will &amp; Testament</a></li>
        <li id="poa_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/power_of_attorney.htm">Power Of Attorney</a></li>
        <li id="livingWill_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/living_will.htm">Living Will</a></li>
        <li id="trusts_menuItem" class="subMenuItem"><a href="/estate_planning/trusts.htm">Trusts</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="probate_menuItem" class="menuItem">
        <a href="probate_administration.htm" title="Estate Administration">Estate Probate Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li id="realEstate_menuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="#" title="Real Estate Transactions">Real Estate</a></li>         
    <li id="medicaid_MenuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="#" title="">Medicaid</a></li>
    <li id="guardianships_menuItem" class="menuItem"><a href="#" title="">Guardianships</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370809/css-html-highlighting-the-full-width-avaialble-to-a-list-item) is why I'm using that particular code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is something wrong, `<ul>`'s can be inside of `<li>`'s, but not other `<ul>`'s.

This is correct...

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>  
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-UL), you cannot have a `<ul>` directly under another `<ul>`. You should nest it inside a `<li>`.

If you're worried about the additional padding/margins, you can remove them with a rule that only applies to `<ul>` elements as direct children of `<li>` elements:

```
li > ul { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

(Or experiment with the best setting for your style)

Comment: Darn.  That makes my problem more difficult.  Thank you for letting me know, however.

Answer (score 2):

BELOW is proper way

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="planning_menuItem" class="menuItem">
        <a href="/estate_planning/" title="Estate Planning">Estate Planning</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <ul class="subMenu">
        <li id="will_menuItem" class="subMenuItem">
            <a href="/estate_planning/last_will_and_testament.htm" title="Last Will and Testaments">Last Will &amp; Testament</a>
        </li>
        <li id="poa_menuItem" class="subMenuItem">
            <a href="/estate_planning/power_of_attorney.htm">Power Of Attorney</a>
        </li>
        <li id="livingWill_menuItem" class="subMenuItem">
            <a href="/estate_planning/living_will.htm">Living Will</a>
        </li>
        <li id="trusts_menuItem" class="subMenuItem">
            <a href="/estate_planning/trusts.htm">Trusts</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="probate_menuItem" class="menuItem">
        <a href="probate_administration.htm" title="Estate Administration">Estate Probate Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li id="realEstate_menuItem" class="menuItem">
        <a href="#" title="Real Estate Transactions">Real Estate</a>
    </li>         
    <li id="medicaid_MenuItem" class="menuItem">
        <a href="#" title="">Medicaid</a>
    </li>
    <li id="guardianships_menuItem" class="menuItem">
        <a href="#" title="">Guardianships</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

as others have said the second way is valid

here's a forked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pBrm/1/) showing some new CSS which should help

summary is that you want to keep the `ul`'s and their `li`'s full width no side padding or margins, so reset all `ul`'s; then make the `a`'s display block so they fill their parent `li`'s - then use `text-indent` to create the indented look of the li's

then however you choose to apply an "active or selected" class - apply it to the `li` OR `a` and any hover changes can be made too.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for going above and beyond. I came to a similar conclusion last night. All I did was wrap the "sub menu header (i.e. Estate Planning) text in it's own div.  Here's a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pBrm/5/).